# Acer Aspire 5742 HDD activity pilot light is always on when I insert a SD card

Tags: 11.04, hard-drive

Ubuntu 11.04: on Acer Aspire 5742 
The HDD activity pilot light is working properly, but when I insert a SD card into the laptop slot, then this HDD pilot light is always on...is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

I have an Acer Aspire 5755-6699 and I was wondering the exact same thing. Except I didn't figure it out until I decided to put the SD card back into my Nikon DSLR. I guess it's a hardware feature of the Acer laptops. It happens when I boot Ubuntu as well as Windows 7. Laptop isn't running any slower with or without the SD card in it regardless of the HDD indication light. Hope this answers your question, or at least puts you in the right direction. Cheers!